# Javascript for in setAttribute

Tags: javascript

At school my teacher changed my code to example down below
and it's not working and I can't understand how it works and fix it.

```js
function _$(e, attrs) {
    var el = document.createElement(e);
    for(a in attrs){
        el.setAttribute(a, attrs[a]);
    }
}

   var $taskMain = _$("section", { "class": "sdfjsf", "id": "taskId", "data-id-number": "sajfsaf"});

//and i have error
//template.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    currentCollon.appendChild($taskMain);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a `return el;` at the end of your `_$` function.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a `return el;` at the end of your `_$` function.

give the result as follows，The `_$` function creates a tag

```
 <section class="sdfjsf" id="taskId",data-id-number:"sajfsaf"></section>
```

This sentence code

```
currentCollon.appendChild($taskMain);
```

Before execution，assume that currentCollon is body

```
<body> 
</body>
```

After execution

```
<body>
<section class="sdfjsf" id="taskId",data-id-number:"sajfsaf"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: What kind of syntax is `id="taskId",data-id-number:"sajfsaf"`?

Comment: I'm very sorry,
<section class="sdfjsf" id="taskId" data-id-number="sajfsaf"></section>